# How can I find the expected time until a random variable is greater than some constant?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, ....$ that are i.i.d. with the same distribution F. If I define $k$ to be a constant and $T$ to be the time until any $X_i$ is greater than $k$, what would be $E(T)$? The approach I thought of doing was to first get: $P(X_i > k ) = 1-F(k)$. Then, I thought about integrating for the expected value, but am not sure about the limits or if this would work. Does anyone have any ideas? thanks!

Comment: How does $X_1$ have a "time"?  Do you mean $X_1(t)$, ie, you have a sequence of iid *stochastic processes*?

Comment: $P\{T > n\} = P\{X_1\leq k, X_2\leq k, \cdots X_n\leq k\} = F(k)^n$ and $E[T] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P\{T > n\}$. Can you sum the series?

Answer (score 1):

It's a typical survival model setup. Your hazard rate is $h=1-F(k)$, so the survival probability through time $t$ is $S(t)=F(k)^t$. The probability to die in $t$ is $S(t-1) h$. Get the expectation: $$\sum_{t=1}^\infty t S(t-1) h=\frac{1}{1-F(k)}$$

Comment: The sum $\sum_{t=1}^\infty t S(t-1) h = \sum_{t=1}^\infty t F(k)]^{t-1}(1-F(k))$  is harder to compute than the one I mentioned in my comment. Even more easily, since the hazard rate is constant at $1-F(k)$, the expected value is just the inverse $\frac{1}{1-F(k)}$ as all survivalists know.